# Vaadin 14 fails to load lumo-color and lumo-typography on Windows 10 machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

We made a simple UI with Vaadin 14 and Spring Boot. The UI runs flawlessly on OSX as well as in a Docker container based on a Linux image.

[image]

However, we don't get it to run on a Windows 10 machine. The app starts and we can access the UI. But all styles are missing. The UI looks totally broken, even though the buttons are working.

[image]

There are no errors in the Java log, but the browser console shows the following:

```
style-gather.js?ee41:216 Could not find style data in module named lumo-color
style-gather.js?ee41:216 Could not find style data in module named lumo-typography
```

What are we missing?

**Edit:**

I pushed the project to https://github.com/tuhrig/vaadin-win-issue

Comment: Is this a production build or just for development?  If prod, have you built a production build?

Comment: It's a development build. On OSX it's also a development build, but in the Docker container its a production build.

Comment: I cloned your project and it looks good on Windows 10

Comment: I cloned and it is like the screen cap, I think vaadin making some stuff too automatic which is failing all :)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, there's some randomness involved. The screenshot above is from my private Windows notebook. However, on the Windows laptop of my colleague this exact same GitHub project looks perfectly fine - but another Vaadin project which looks pretty much the same isn't working on his machine... The assume it's some class loading or Spring issue. But I'm unable to debugg it.

Comment: Have you tried all this: https://mvysny.github.io/Vaadin-troubleshooting/